# How to select two different choices from two ComboBoxes that use the same List of choices

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a List of choices:
`{"Bubble Sort" , "Selection Sort" , "Quick Sort" , "Merge Sort"}`

And two comboboxes: `Algorithm1` and `Algorithm2`

And I did this:

```
private List<string> AlgorithmList = new List<string>() {
    "Bubble Sort", "Selection Sort" , "Merge Sort" , "Quick Sort"
};
Algorithm1.DataSource = AlgorithmList;
Algorithm2.DataSource = AlgorithmList;
```

I want to do this: If I choose one of the algorithm which is available in `Algorithm1`, it will no longer be available in `Algorithm2`.
I thought if I modify the List, it also change the comboboxes, like remove choice from the List if its selected but it didn't work. Please show me a way and tell me what be hind the code when im say:

```
combobox1.DataSource = List<object>;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple method using LINQ's [`.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2) to filter the `ComboBoxes` lists of items, based on a user selection. The initial content of the second ComboBox (`ComboBox2`) is pre-filtered, to exclude `ComboBox1` first element in the list.

In `Form.Load()` or in the class constructor:

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = AlgorithmList;
ComboBox2.DataSource = AlgorithmList
         .Where(elm => elm != ComboBox1.GetItemText(ComboBox1.Items[0])).ToList();
```

When a item is selected in `ComboBox1`, `ComboBox2.DataSource` is filtered to exclude the selected item:

```
private void ComboBox1_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ComboBox2.DataSource = AlgorithmList
             .Where(elm => elm != ComboBox1.GetItemText(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy.
Use the BindingList class in the DrawItem event. The BindingList class is a DataSource of a ComboBox.
The DrawItem event consists of two parameters. Take the index from the parameters of DrawItemEventArgs and create a conditional statement.

Here is an example:

BindingList _comboItems = new BindingList();

private void Combo_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)

```
    {
        Brush brush = null;
        ComboBox combo = (ComboBox)sender;

        if (TRUE)
        {
            //SELECT
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(SystemBrushes.Window, e.Bounds);
            brush = ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) > 0) ? SystemBrushes.HotTrack : SystemBrushes.ControlText;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(_comboItems[e.Index].Text, combo.Font, brush, e.Bounds);
        }
        else
        {
            e.DrawBackground();
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.DarkGray, e.Bounds);
            brush = ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) > 0) ? SystemBrushes.HighlightText : SystemBrushes.ControlText;
            e.Graphics.DrawString(_comboItems[e.Index].Text, combo.Font, brush, e.Bounds);
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        }

    }
```

Comment: your answer is little bit hard to understand for me cause im new to C# . im trying to figure what you suggested me . Thanks for your help